# Kubuntu upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 failed

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, kubuntu, 15.10

Some time ago I triggered upgrade from Kubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 and it failed (I forgot why and with what message). When I issued `sudo do-release-upgrade` it failed with message:

`E: The value 'wily' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

Full log-output (with errors): -> [paste.ubuntu.com](https://paste.ubuntu.com/18051416/)

Then I tried `sudo apt-get autoclean` but it failed with similar message. So I decided to revert `/etc/apt/sources.list` with command `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade /etc/apt/sources.list`, then I did `sudo apt-get update` and repeated release upgrade. Unfortunately it failed with the same result...

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `E: The value 'wily' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources` occured during repositories reconfiguration. It was caused by content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` where `wily` was set instead of `xenial`.

I changed this file's content to `APT::Default-Release "xenial";` and next upgrade attempt finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to achieve the upgrade:

1st goto -> Software Sources -> Updates

There is a field that allows the system to check for new versions:
LTS only / any / never. Select "any" LTS will only be available with 16.04.1 Just remember to set it back to LTs before Oct.2016 if it's not in your nature to go in sync with every new release of (K)Ubuntu.

Then open the update-manager from the menu. After you have checked for updates, it will inform you about the availibility of a system-upgrade.

It's always recommended to read the [Release-Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu) beforehand for "Known issues". You find them in 7. Further information. It may also be a good idea to look at the [Ubuntu-RN](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes) as this gives the underlying system, like drivers.

In case you are not certain if your sources.list is messed up right now:

You can easily reset the sources-list to it's origin without touching it with editor, as this was identified mainly to be a cause of errors.

`kdesudo software-properties-kde`

This will raise a GUI-window, with a reset-button in the left-bottom corner(+ other option). What does this button? It retrieves the most current list of standard-sources via Internet connection from Canonical.

As in the log-list you have offered the term vivid appears, you are requesting an impossible solution. Vivid is not on the standard servers as it is EOL (End of life cycle).

Comment: I used to use GUI, but it failed from time to time in the past and I had to use command line anyway. This is how I got used to CLI way of doing upgrade. Anyway this time it also failed from GUI...

Comment: Any error-comments you can post? If it's long than use https://paste.ubuntu.com and quote the link in your initial question.

Another option is by the way to use a DVD and add it to your package-sources. You will be represented with the question if you put it in the DVD-drive. Still wonder why the officially recommended method shouldn't work OOTB. These days you don't even have to ppa-purge/de-install external software (They are listed in etc/apt/sources.list.d/). The ppa-sources just get deactivated, that was impressive.

Comment: GUI does `do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE` which seems pretty similar to what I did.

I have added full output of my command.

Comment: Have you tried to switching to the main ubuntu-server in the sofware-sources programm already?

By the way changing the sources-list manually is not recommended, it works with Debian, but it shows failures in (K)Ubuntu.

Comment: Try disabling the Partners-repository - before upgrade. Right now can't remember where I read this. Worth a try... Just enable it after the upgrade.

Comment: Added some info in the answer about your sources.list & how to fix it.

Comment: `kdesudo software-properties-kde` did not solve problem and it also did not remove Vivid from repos. So I had to revert sources.list manually, then did updates and cleans and used GUI to reset repos to main server. After this operation /etc/apt/sources.list looked like this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/18085389/  Upgrade failed again: https://paste.ubuntu.com/18085487/  This is where 'wily' is still present in my repos definitions: https://paste.ubuntu.com/18085577/

Comment: Just a quick reply now: If you have installed any software from ppa that comes from "Precise" the next valid version to replace this would of course be-> Wily. So the assumption is that you have to get rid of these or update them to the Wily-Version. I have more time to look into that in the evening today. Note also that GCC in Xenial is a newer version.

Comment: Sorry mate I'm signing off from this stupid forum, as I get a stupid notification to move this support to a chat.  The 1st thinmg you have to do is get your system in a stable state! Try kubuntuforums.org (w/o chat). Sorry. I do chat, but only in private.